# How to stop a "Foreground Service" with .addAction from Notification Building using Pending Intent and Broadcast Receivers in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, foreground-service

I have a notification builder using notification manager, I implemented a foreground service using the startForegroud() method. However, I'm quite confused on how to use broadcast receivers to stop the service using stopForeground(true) and stopSelf(). Here's what I have so far.

In my MyForegroundService class, I have the following.

```html
class MyForegroundServices : Service() {
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Thread {
            while (true) {
                Log.e("Service", "Service is running...")
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000)
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }.start()

        val CHANNELID = "Foreground Service ID"
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNELID,
            CHANNELID,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        )

        val foregroundIntent = Intent(this, NotificationReceiver::class.java).apply {
            action = "STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
            putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0)
        }
        val foregroundPendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, foregroundIntent, 0)


        getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java).createNotificationChannel(channel)
        val notification = Notification.Builder(this, CHANNELID)
            .setContentText("Service is running")
            .setContentTitle("Service enabled")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Stop", foregroundPendingIntent)

        //Any ID will do at the moment
        startForeground(1001, notification.build())

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Now I don't know if that's how to properly implement a pendingIntent, and I also don't have any idea what to put in my receiver class using Broadcast receivers

```html
class NotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")

    }
}
```

Looking forward and thank you in advanced for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `PendingIntent` is fine.

If you want your `BroadcastReceiver` to simply stop your `Service`, use something like this for `onReceive()`:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    context.stopService(Intent(context, MyForegroundServices::class.java))
}
```

If you want to use this `BroadcastReceiver` to do other things as well, you can interrogate the `Intent` argument that is passed in to `onReceive()` and use the ACTION or "extras" to perform whatever other functions you want.